# What's the meaning of Prolog operator '->'

Tags: prolog

I have noticed the use of the operator -> in some Prolog programs, but its meaning is unknown to me.
This is an example of its use:

```
swish_add_user(User, Passwd, Fields) :-
    phrase("$1$", E, _), % use Unix MD5 hashes
    crypt(Passwd, E),
    string_codes(Hash, E),
    Entry = passwd(User, Hash, Fields),
    absolute_file_name(swish(passwd), File,
    [access(write)]),
    ( exists_file(File)
    -> http_read_passwd_file(File, Data)
    ; Data = []
    ),
    ( selectchk(passwd(User, _, _), Data, Entry, NewData)
    -> true
    ; append(Data, [Entry], NewData)
    ),
    http_write_passwd_file(File, NewData).
```

What is its use in this clause? When should I use this operator and when not?

PS: The code segment is taken from the [authenticate.pl](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swish/blob/master/lib/authenticate.pl) file in the [swish](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swish) repository, an excellent implementation of a [Prolog IDE online](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/), by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joel76's answer gives what is probably by far the most common usage of the `->/2` control construct, which is defined in [ISO Prolog](http://www.deransart.fr/prolog/bips.html). The description given for `Goal1 -> Goal2` in the [GNU Prolog manual](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec67) is:

> `Goal1 -> Goal2` first executes `Goal1` and, in case of success, removes all choice-points created by `Goal1` and executes `Goal2`. This control construct **acts like an if-then** (`Goal1` is the test part and `Goal2` the then part). Note that if `Goal1` fails `->/2` fails also. **`->/2` is often combined with `;/2` to define an *if-then-else*** as follows: `Goal1 -> Goal2 ; Goal3`. Note that `Goal1 -> Goal2` is the first argument of the `(;)/2` and `Goal3` (the else part) is the second argument. Such an if-then-else control construct first creates a choice-point for the else-part (intuitively associated with `;/2`) and then executes `Goal1`. In case of success, all choice-points created by `Goal1` together with the choice-point for the else-part are removed and `Goal2` is executed. If `Goal1` fails then `Goal3` is executed.

It doesn't act like a *mathematical logical implication* (as its symbolic form might suggest) because, in such an implication clause, `F -> T` is true, whereas in Prolog, as mentioned above, if `Goal1` fails, then the `->/2` expression fails.

It's important to note operator precedence in this case. In Prolog, the order of precedence is `,`, then `->`, then `;`. Thus, as stated in the description, in an if-then-else construct, `Goal1 -> Goal2 ; Goal3`, the `Goal1 -> Goal2` expression is the first argument of `;/2`. Here is what happens in various cases:

```
Goal1  ->  Goal2  ;  Goal3     if-then-else  Notes
-----      -----     -----     ------------  -----
Succeeds   Succeeds  NE*       Succeeds      Goal1 choice point removed
                                             Goal2 choice point remains (if it exists)
Succeeds   Fails     NE        Fails         Goal1 choice point removed
Fails      NE        Succeeds  Succeeds      Goal3 choice point remains (if it exists)
Fails      NE        Fails     Fails

*NE = not executed
```

Because of the precedence, the *if-then-else* constructs are often parenthesized, as in the example:

```
( selectchk(passwd(User, _, _), Data, Entry, NewData)
-> true
; append(Data, [Entry], NewData)
),
blah-blah
```

If the parentheses were not there, then `blah-blah` would become part of the *else* and not executed if `selectchk` succeeds.

There is also something interesting that happens to the choice points. If `Goal1` succeeds, Prolog will call `Goal2`, etc, but won't backtrack to more solutions, if they exist, for `Goal1`. To illustrate:

```
a(1).
a(2).

test :-
    (  a(X)
    -> write(X), nl
    ;  write('no a'), nl
    ).

| ?- test.
1

yes
```

In the above, Prolog didn't go back to find `X = 2` for `a(X)`. On the other hand, backtracking can occur for the `else`:

```
foo :-
    (  false
    -> write('not gonna happen'), nl
    ;  a(X),
       write(X), nl
    ).

| ?- foo.
1

true ? ;
2

yes
```

Backtracking also occurs for `Goal2`:

```
foo :-
    (   true
    ->  a(X), write(X), nl
    ;   write('else'), nl
    ).

| ?- foo.
1

true ? ;
2

yes
```

But as you can see, once the `Goal2` path is chosen, there's no backtracking to the `else` (`Goal3`) when solutions for `Goal2` are exhausted. A might be expected, executions of `Goal2` versus `Goal3` are mutually exclusive depending upon the result of `Goal1`.

Answer (score 2):

It is the if/then/else in Prolog, for example

```
( X mod 2 =:= 0
-> writeln(even)
;  writeln(odd)).
```