# Prolog. Break integer in the amount of natural terms

Tags: prolog, visual-prolog

My task is: Find the number of partitions of a positive integer in the amount of natural terms.
For example: N=5. Answer is 7, because 5: {1,1,1,1,1}, {2,1,1,1}, {2,2,1}, {3,1,1}, {3,2}, {4,1}, {5}

I wrote a solution on JS:

```
function pcount(number, limit) { 
 if (limit === 0) {
  if (number === 0) {
   return 1;
  }
  return 0;
 }

 if (limit <= number) {
  return pcount(number, limit - 1) + pcount(number - limit, limit);
 }

 return pcount(number, number);
}
```

but now i'm trying to write it using Prolog, but there are some difficulties with `pcount(number, limit - 1) + pcount(number - limit, limit);` statement.

Here is my code:

```
PREDICATES
    check(integer,integer,integer)
    check(integer,integer)
CLAUSES
    check(0,0,Result):-
        Result=1.
    check(_,0,Result):-
        Result=0.
    check(Number,Limit,Result):-
        Limit<=Number,!,
        NN=Limit-1,
        RR=Number-Limit,
        check(Number,NN,Result1),
        check(RR,Limit,Result2),
        Result=Result1+Result2.
    check(A,B):-
        check(A,B,X),
        write(X).

    %check(number, limit - 1) + check(number - limit, limit);

GOAL
    check(2,2).
```

but it doesn't work. Error at this predicate: `check(Number,Limit,Result)`. How can I combine the results of two calls of predicates: `check(Number, Limit-1)+check(Number-Limit,Limit)`?

Comment: Prolog doesn't have *functions* but *predicates*. A predicate succeeds or fails and does not return a value. But you can instantiate an variable argument with a result (*e.g.*, `pcount(5, 5, Result)`). I'm not sure why you're concerned about that. It's a fundamentally different language. As far as just mapping an if-then-else, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051798/whats-the-meaning-of-prolog-operator) might be of interest to you.

Comment: I keep forgetting that Turbo/Visual prolog allows `<=` in place of `=<`. :p

Comment: You might want to go through a basic Prolog tutorial before tackling this problem. Expressions such as, `pcount(Number,Limit-1)+pcount(Number-Limit,Limit)` arent going to do at all what you think it's going to do.

Comment: ty, but `Goal1  ->  Goal2  ;  Goal3` statement doesn't work in visual prolog.

Comment: Unfortunately, Visual Prolog deviates significantly from what is considered to be standard Prolog. What you've updated, though, is very close to correct. Your second clause, `check(_, 0, Result)` needs to ensure that the number is > 0 to avoid overlap with the first case. And you need a clause to handle `Number > Limit`. What exactly is the *error at this predicate...*? FYI, you can just write, `check(0, 0, 1).` instead of `check(0, 0, R) :- R = 1.` (I *think* Visual Prolog lets you do that - it's standard Prolog.)

Comment: Minor correction to my comment: you don't need a clause for `Number > Limit` if that's not a successful case (you want that case to fail). It's a success case in your original javascript-ish code.

Comment: I have error: `Message:1010 Stack overflow`. And yes, I rewrote my predicates to `check(0,0,1)` and `check(A,0,0):- A>0`. It works, ty

Comment: But I can't understand what wrong in my recursion and where in stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is very close to correct, but requires a little more constraint. The existing clause is recursing into negative values of `Limit`. Here's a minor update which should resolve that issue, along with some minor tweaks:

```
check(0, 0, 1).
check(N, 0, 0) :-
    N > 0.                   % Added constraint N > 0
                             %    avoids overlap with first clause
check(Number, Limit, Result):-
    Limit > 0,               % Added constraint Limit > 0 avoids overlap
                             %    with first clause and negative values
    Limit <= Number, !,
    NN = Limit - 1,
    RR = Number - Limit,
    check(Number, NN, Result1),
    check(RR, Limit, Result2),
    Result = Result1 + Result2.
check(Number, Limit, Result) :-    % Case were Limit > Number as in your
    Limit > Number,                %    original non-Prolog code
    check(Number, Number, Result).

check(A, B):-
    check(A, B, X),
    write(X).
```

Comment: wow, ty! It works. I completely forgot about the last condition `pcount(number, number)`. Thank you for your help, advices and patience.

Comment: @HelterShelter I'm glad this worked for you. :) Would you be able to accept it as an answer?

Comment: oh, sorry, I'm novice on stackoverflow and forgot about it. I marked it