# Use of conditionals in Prolog

Tags: syntax, prolog

I am confused about how conditionals are used in prolog. While *Example 1* is the case for a conditional, *Example 2* shows a case where it says `NewPos = Exit` on the other side of the `->` operator. Is it checking if `NewPos` is equal to `Exit` or is it the case that the value `Exit` is being assigned to `NewPos`? Shouldn't an `is` be used to assign values in prolog?

Sorry if this is a very basic syntax question.

**Example 1**

```
Current = b(_,Cost,NewPos),
( Exit=none   -> backtrack_path(Current,Visited,RPath)
; Exit=b(5,5) -> backtrack_path(Current,Visited,RPath)
```

**Example 2**

```
Current = b(_,Cost,NewPos),
( Exit=none -> backtrack_path(Current,Visited,RPath)
; otherwise -> NewPos = Exit,
             backtrack_path(Current,Visited,RPath)
```

Comment: Does `Exit` occur prior to the snippets you show?

Comment: `NewPos = Exit` does not check if `NewPos` is equal to `Exit`. You have to remember that this is Prolog, and `=/2` is a *unification* operator, not an equality check or assignment. It attempts to *unify* `NewPos` with `Exit` and, it either succeeds or fails. And what does `otherwise` mean?

Comment: The `otherwise` is for a situation where : 
`( condition A ->; `
    `otherwise    -> `
So basically like an `if` and an `else` from a language like C.
So when `NewPos` and `Exit` are unified, does it stay that way? (there might be a lack of understanding of how unification works on my behalf).

Comment: I see, so *otherwise* is just a placeholder for real code. Regarding the unification, if a predicate clause unifies `Exit` and `NewPos` and they become *instantiated* (which will occur during unification if one is instantiated and the other is not, and unification succeeds), they do remain instantiated for the rest of the clause execution. They can then only be reinstantiated on backtracking (if that occurs back to a point prior to instantiation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a more detailed look at the Prolog `->` operator, see [What's the meaning of Prolog operator '->'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051798/whats-the-meaning-of-prolog-operator/29052629#29052629). Your examples are covered below.

**Example 1:**

```
Current = b(_,Cost,NewPos),
```

Unifies `Current` with the term, `b(_, Cost, NewPos)`. *Unficiation* in Prolog is *not* the same as assignment. In *unification*, Prolog will attempt to match the two arguments of `=/2` possibly instantiating variables on either side to achieve the unification. If, for example, `Current`, `Cost` and `NewPos` are all uninstantiated, then `Current` will be instantiated with `b(_, Cost, NewPos)` (using the *same* variables, `Cost` and `NewPos`. If, later on, `Cost` is instantiated with, say, `10`, then `Current` will also become, `b(_, 10, NewPos)`, in effect.

```
( Exit=none   -> backtrack_path(Current,Visited,RPath)
; Exit=b(5,5) -> backtrack_path(Current,Visited,RPath)
```

`;` has lower [precedence](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=operators) than `->`, so this is, in effect:

```
(   Exit=none
->  backtrack_path(Current,Visited,RPath)
;   (   Exit=b(5,5)
    ->  backtrack_path(Current,Visited,RPath),
        ...
    ),
    ...
)
```

`Exit = none` will attempt to unify `Exit` and the atom, `none`. It will succeed if `Exit` is uninstantiated (and will then instantiate `Exit` with `none`), or can succeed if `Exit` is already instantiated as `none`. It will fail if `Exit` is instantiated with any term that doesn't match `none`.

If `Exit = none` succeeds, then the first `backtrack_path(Current, Visited, RPath)` is called. If it fails, then an attempt is made to unify `Exit` with `b(5,5)`. If the prior `Exit = none` failed, then we got to this point because `Exit` was already unified with something that didn't match `none`, and it will succeed `Exit = b(5,5)` only if it was already unified with a term that looks like, `b(X, Y)`. Otherwise, it will also fail. If it succeeds, then, again, `backtrack_path(Current, Visited, RPath)` will be called.

**Example 2:**

```
Current = b(_,Cost,NewPos),
( Exit=none -> backtrack_path(Current,Visited,RPath)
; otherwise -> NewPos = Exit,
             backtrack_path(Current,Visited,RPath)
```

`,` has highest precedence, followed by `->`, followed by `;`. So this is effectively:

```
Current = b(_,Cost,NewPos),
(   Exit=none
->  backtrack_path(Current,Visited,RPath)
;   (   otherwise
    ->  (   NewPos = Exit,
            backtrack_path(Current,Visited,RPath),
            ...
        ),
        ...
    ),
    ...
 )
```

See the discussion above about unification. If `Exit = none` succeeds, then `backtrack_path(Current, Visited, RPath)` is called. Otherwise, then then `otherwise` call is done (NOTE that if `otherwise` is a block of code, then operator precedence can affect the grouping I show above, so I'm assuming `otherwise` is a block which has precedence over the following `->`).

If `otherwise` succeeds, then Prolog attempts `NewPos = Exit`, and if that succeeds, it will move on to call, `backtrack_path(Current, Visited, RPath)`. If the `NewPos = Exit` unification fails, then, in this case, lacking an "else" or "OR" (`;`) type of expression, it might backtrack all the way to `Current = b(_, Cost, NewPos)`. Where it backtracks to depends completely upon what other code you have in this clause (it's a bit hypothetically presented, so it could be anything).

**Regarding `is/2`**

`is/2` is used to (a) evaluate a numeric expression as its second argument, and (b) unify the result of the expression evaluation with the first argument. Here are some examples, also showing the contrast with `=/2` (unification):

```
| ?- X = A + B.

X = A+B

yes
```

Here, `X` is *unified* with the term, `A + B`. So `X` is now instantiated with the term `A+B` (which is the term, `'+'(A, B)`)

```
| ?- A = 2, B = 3, X = A + B.

A = 2
B = 3
X = 2+3

yes
```

`X` is *unified* with the term, `A + B`. `A` is unified with `2` (and so `A` is *instantiated* with the value `2`), and `B` is unified with `3`. So `X` is unified with `2+3` (or `'+'(2,3)).

```
| ?- A = 2, B = 3, X is A + B.

A = 2
B = 3
X = 5

yes
```

The expression on the right hand side of `is` (the second argument to `is/2`) is evaluated yielding `5`. Then `X` is instantiated to `5`.

```
| ?- A = 2, X is A + B.
uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,(is)/2)
```

`B` isn't instantiated, so the expression, `A + B` cannot be evaluated, so `is/2` fails due to an instantiation error.

```
| ?- A = 2, B = 3, Z = 5, Z is A + B.

A = 2
B = 3
Z = 5

yes
```

`A`, `B`, and `Z` are all instantiated to numeric values, and `Z is A + B` succeeds since `A + B` evaluates to `5`, which is unifiable with `Z` which also has the value `5`.

```
| ?- A = 2, B = 3, Z = 4, Z is A + B.

no
```

`A`, `B`, and `Z` are all instantiated to numeric values, and `Z is A + B` fails since `A + B` evaluates to `5`, which is not unifiable with `Z` which has the value `4`.

```
| ?- A = 2, B = 3, X = A + B, Z is X.

A = 2
B = 3
X = 2+3
Z = 5

yes
```

`X` is unified with the term, `A + B`, which is the term `2 + 3` since `A` has been instantiated with `2`, and `B` with `3`. `Z` is unified with the evaluation of the expression `X` (which is `2 + 3`) and so has the value `5`.