# some issue in my prolog code

Tags: prolog, logic, swi-prolog

i am new to prolog and have written some code in prolog simply to show some message but when i run it produce some error that :

1) Syntax error: Unexpected end of clause

2)ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: 
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: .course_crh .

**Here is my code**

```
gpa(0).
gpa(0.1).
gpa(0.2).
gpa(0.3).
gpa(0.4).
gpa(0.5).
gpa(0.6).
gpa(0.7).
gpa(0.8).
gpa(0.9).
gpa(1.0).
gpa(1.1).
gpa(1.2).
gpa(1.3).
gpa(1.4).
gpa(1.5).
gpa(1.6).
gpa(1.7).
gpa(1.8).
gpa(1.9).
gpa(2.0).
gpa(2.1).
gpa(2.2).
gpa(2.3).
gpa(2.4).
gpa(2.5).
gpa(2.6).
gpa(2.7).
gpa(2.8).
gpa(2.9).
gpa(3.0).
gpa(3.1).
gpa(3.2).
gpa(3.3).
gpa(3.4).
gpa(3.5).
gpa(3.6).
gpa(3.7).
gpa(3.8).
gpa(3.9).
gpa(4.0).
course_crh(gpa(X)):-
write('Please Enter gpa'),
read(X),
(( X>=2.0, X=<4.0)->
write('Max 18 credit are allowed');write('Less than 18 credit hrs allowed').
```

**What i want**

that calling on course_crh() it print the message to enter gpa then check in condition and print the final message depends on my input value.

i have tried this 
[Use of conditionals in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830979/use-of-conditionals-in-prolog)
and
this [Conditional Statements in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003045/conditional-statements-in-prolog)

but failed again and again

Comment: You missed a parenthesis :  write('Less than 18 credit hrs allowed'). should be  write('Less than 18 credit hrs allowed') ).

Comment: @coder i have corrected this but still its not working ...

Comment: In what part this doesn't work? At least to me it doesn't throws errors ,do you mean it gives wrong result? describe....

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This means showing exactly how you load the code that you show, how you call it, what happens, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: BTW, note that all the `gpa(...)` facts you have in your program at the moment are not at all used in `course_crh/1`. For a minimal example, you should remove them from the question, because they don't influence the final result in any way!